# ローカルで起動する api サーバーに対して、名前をつけて browser からアクセスしたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, network, macos

Mac で開発をしています。この上で、ローカルでのみ起動・アクセスしたい、 rails アプリ(API サーバープログラム) がいくつかあります。このようなサービスに対して、独自のホストネームを付与して、アクセスできたら便利だと考えました。

例えば、 http://my-local-superservice にアクセスすると、 localhost の 3000 (ないし、サービス毎に予め設定しておくポート) に接続しにいくような設定です。

質問

- このようなことは可能でしょうか? 可能な場合、どのような設定になるでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) が、自分の欲しかったものの様子です。

```
brew install puma/puma/puma-dev
sudo puma-dev -setup

cd ~/.puma-dev
ln -s ~/Path/to/my-local-superservice

puma-dev -d pdev
```

をすると、 `my-local-superservice.pdev:9280` でアクセス可能になりました。

Answer (score 1):

railsアプリをApacheで動かすようにして、名前ベースのバーチャルホストを設定すればできそうな気がします。

その上で、hostsで ホスト名を 127.0.0.1 に紐付け、ブラウザでホスト名でアクセスすればApacheが適切なバーチャルホストにリクエストを割り振ってくれます。

Answer (score 0):

固定IPを割り当てた上で、DNSで対象のIPアドレスに希望のホスト名を紐付けるのは如何でしょうか。
手っ取り早くはローカルのhostsファイルを直接編集する方法です。

参考
https://qiita.com/junker919/items/cc15653a681e2dcd79ea

```
sudo vi /private/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1  my-local-superservice
```

Comment: /private/etc/hosts から localhost を取り除くのは問題があります。どうしても hosts ファイルで名前解決したいのなら、
    `127.0.0.1 localhost my-local-supserservice`
とすべきです。

Answer (score 0):

lvh.me を使うのはいかがでしょうか。 lvh.me および *.lvh.me がすべて 127.0.0.1 に解決されるように設定されたドメインです。(このようなドメインは他にもあるようです)